# StartDate invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two SELECT statment which I connect using `UNION` and I get error

```
ORA-00904: "PUSD2"."STARTDATE": invalid identifier
```

Since I create first one SELECT statment and run and I get result, and second also, so I run separatly and it works perfect. But when I use UNION I get error pusd2.StartDate invalid identifier.

```
SELECT * FROM project_users_schedule_dates pusd1
 WHERE pusd1.UserID = 196 AND 
  pusd1.StartDate >= '2020-04-27' AND pusd1.EndDate <= '2020-06-06'  
   UNION 
   SELECT * FROM project_users_schedule_dates pusd2
    WHERE pusd2.UserID = 196 AND 
    pusd2.StartDate <= '2020-04-27' AND pusd2. EndDate >= '2020-06-06' 
     ORDER  BY pusd2.StartDate
```

What is wrong here ? What I made wrong ?

Table structure `project_users_schedule_dates`

[image]

Comment: can you provide the structure of the table `project_users_schedule_dates` ?

Comment: Sure, I edit my question

Comment: That's the table data. The structure would show the data types. Are STARTDATE and ENDDATE strings? Also please post data as text not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error likely stems from using an alias in the second union in your `ORDER BY` clause.  However, I might suggest writing your query this way instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM project_users_schedule_dates
WHERE
    UserID = 196 AND 
    (StartDate >= '2020-04-27' AND EndDate <= '2020-06-06' OR
     StartDate <= '2020-04-27' AND EndDate >= '2020-06-06');
```

This approach brings together the critera from both sides of the union in a single `WHERE` clause.  It then filters duplicates using `DISTINCT`, instead of the union.  Note that in general doing `SELECT *` in a union query is not desirable, because it makes it impossible to see which columns are being included.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `ORDER BY` clause. If you use `UNION`, you have to put the order by in an outline query

```
SQL> create table t ( c1 date ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values ( sysdate ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> select t.c1 from t union all select x.c1 from t x order by x.c1 ;
select t.c1 from t union all select x.c1 from t x order by x.c1
                                                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "X"."C1": invalid identifier
```

You have to use an outline query with order by out of the union ( see below ) or use another approximation like the one provided in the other answer.

```
SQL> select * from ( select t.c1 from t union all select x.c1 from t x ) order by c1 ;

C1
---------
27-AUG-20
27-AUG-20
```

Comment: you re welcome ;) . As you might see there are several options for solving the issue

Comment: Yes I see. But whatever  I choose I get different result. And I dont know which way is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, the last line of your query should be just

```
ORDER BY StartDate
```

(of course, if there's such a column in that query).

Comment: Yes, it is column StartDate.

Comment: Good. Then it should be OK.